# mysql v8.0.16 unable to initialize the database following fresh installation

Tags: mysql

After a fresh installation of mysql 8.0.16 I get these errors:

```
2019-06-02T06:00:29.777041Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] C:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.16) initializing of server in progress as process 11288
2019-06-02T06:00:29.839450Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2019-06-02T06:00:29.839647Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2019-06-02T06:00:29.840528Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-06-02T06:00:29.840565Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory C:\mysql\data\ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
2019-06-02T06:00:29.892808Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-06-02T06:00:29.897636Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happened before you got this error message? Did you take any measures to try and overcome the problem? Did your search engine of choice give anything? Also, please use the formatting tools at the top of the edit window - it helps readability! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Looks like the wrong permissions on C:\mysql\data. [Troubleshooting a Microsoft Windows MySQL Server Installation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html)

Comment: What did you change in the configuration?